# how to prevent others than the top most gameobject receive clicked event in a stacked gameobjects

Tags: unity-game-engine, onclick, gameobject

I have an object with a `BoxCollider2D`, which is lying under an object with a `BoxCollider`. (Details is an UI (I use NGUI asset) with a `BoxCollider` lying on top of a `GameObject` with a `BoxCollider2D`). The UI object has a script which implements `OnClick()` and the `GameObject` has a script implementing `OnMouseDown()`. When I click the UI object, click events fire from the `GameObject` as well.

I just want the UI object fire event when they are stacking on each other. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: When you say that the UI element uses OnClick() you mean that it is a Button object correct?

Comment: yes, it is actually a UI Button comes from NGUI library

Comment: you can't realistically use "NGUI" these days.  change to the ordinary Unity UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include using `UnityEngine.EventSystems;` In your `OnMouseDown()` function, add `if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())` then put all the code that is suppose to run when mouse is down inside the `if` statement.

```
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public void OnMouseDown()
{
 if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject())
 {
  //Put all your code for your gameobject here
 }
}
```

That should work but if it doesn't, Watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EVZiv7DLU6E) video for other ways to do this.

Comment: Just realized you use NGUI. My solution is for Unity UI. No reason to be using NGUI at this time because Unity new UI is optimized and can do what NGUI can do and even more.

Comment: yes actually i'm doing outsourcing and the NGUI library was installed previously and thus I reluctantly have to continue using it. The EventSystem solution didnt work on NGUI but many thanks for your support :D

Comment: hey sorry for the misunderstanding I didn't put exclamation when I wrote the if condition. Thank you very much for the solution!

Comment: if you have a client with an incredibly old project that uses NGUI, just click "delete" and do it in ordinary UI.  if it's deprecated, it's deprecated you know?  no reason to waste their time or your own!

Comment: @JoeBlow I thought about telling him that but believe me, some clients are crazy as hell and wants everything to be done their way even though it's wrong. Met someone who wanted me to use OnGUI to finish their work.....